Detect the table where the sortable item comes from
I have two tables where I can drag and drop items between tables and drag and drop items within the same table. I want to detect the table from which the item is coming.
Receive event only fires when items come from other table. I also need to detect when item comes only from the same table and once item is dropped. Any ideas? See demo


$("#peopleTable1 tbody").sortable({
  connectWith: "#peopleTable2 tbody",
  helper: function(e, tr) {
    const $originals = tr.children();
    const $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
      // Set helper cell sizes to match the original sizes
      $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width());
    });
    return $helper;
  },
  start: function(e, ui) {},
  stop: function(e, ui) {},
  receive: function(e, ui) {
    console.log("Users2 -- Users1")
  },
  axis: "xy",
});

$("#peopleTable2 tbody").sortable({
  connectWith: "#peopleTable1 tbody",
  helper: function(e, tr) {
    const $originals = tr.children();
    const $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
      // Set helper cell sizes to match the original sizes
      $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width());
    });
    return $helper;
  },
  start: function(e, ui) {},
  update: function(e, ui) {

  },
  receive: function(e, ui) {
    console.log("Users1 -- Users2")
  },
  axis: "xy",
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table id="peopleTable1">
  <thead class="thead-acu">
    <tr>
      <th class="col-30p">Name</th>
      <th class="col-35p">Age</th>
      <th class="col">Sex</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>Boy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>David</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Boy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Martha</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>Girl</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="peopleTable2">
  <thead class="thead-acu">
    <tr>
      <th class="col-30p">Name</th>
      <th class="col-35p">Age</th>
      <th class="col">Sex</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Boy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laura</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>Girl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ELisabeth</td>
      <td>73</td>
      <td>Girl</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




To achieve your goal you need to do multiple updates:
a) Assign the common class to <tbody> of both tables and merge 2 sortable({...}) codes into one.
b) For each row <tr> of the table add data-attribute(data-table-id) and provide the corresponding table id into it.
c) Use the stop option to capture the event.
d) Check the data attribute of the dropped/sorted ui.item element and compare it with the current table id. (using ui.item.closest('table')[0].id)
e) If both are different then raise an alert from a different table and then change the data-attribute value. (put current table ID into it)
f) If both are the same then alert from the same table and do nothing.
Working snippet:


$("#peopleTable1 > tbody,#peopleTable2 > tbody").sortable({
  connectWith: ".contentEditable",
  helper: function(e, tr) {
    const $originals = tr.children();
    const $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width());
    });
    return $helper;
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.item.data('table-id') != ui.item.closest('table')[0].id) {
      alert('from different table');
      //this will change attribute value,but it will not reflect on browser
      ui.item.data('table-id', ui.item.closest('table')[0].id);
      //To show changed value on browser use below code,You can skip it as well if not required
      ui.item.attr('data-table-id', ui.item.closest('table')[0].id);
    } else {
      alert('from same table');
    }
  },
  axis: "xy",
});
table {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table id="peopleTable1">
  <thead class="thead-acu">
    <tr>
      <th class="col-30p">Name</th>
      <th class="col-35p">Age</th>
      <th class="col">Sex</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="contentEditable">
    <tr data-table-id="peopleTable1">
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>Boy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-table-id="peopleTable1">
      <td>David</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Boy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-table-id="peopleTable1">
      <td>Martha</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>Girl</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="peopleTable2">
  <thead class="thead-acu">
    <tr>
      <th class="col-30p">Name</th>
      <th class="col-35p">Age</th>
      <th class="col">Sex</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="contentEditable">
    <tr data-table-id="peopleTable2">
      <td>John</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Boy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-table-id="peopleTable2">
      <td>Laura</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>Girl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-table-id="peopleTable2">
      <td>ELisabeth</td>
      <td>73</td>
      <td>Girl</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



